# Update comma separated ids with related values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to find a way that makes sense to update all the comma separated ids in a column in table1 with their related values from another table. Note, there are no related ROW ids between the tables as the second table is a reference table.

The format (which I didn't create) is like:

**Items Table 1**

```
    id | color_ids
    ---+----------
     1 | 2,5
     2 | 1
     3 | 2,3,9 
etc...
```

**Colors Table 2**

```
    id | color_name
    ---+-----------
     1 | red
     2 | yellow
     3 | green 
etc...
```

What I need to end up with is an updated table 1 column (or a new column) like:

**Items Table 1**

```
    id | color_ids
    ---+--------------------
     1 | yellow,purple
     2 | red
     3 | yellow,green,orange
etc...
```

Update: The reason I need the format as stated is the db will be updated with data periodically and prepped for export, and I can't change the incoming structure.

Comment: No, what you should end up with is a different table design. Is this an option?

Comment: I realize the design is not good, but working with what I inherited. Adding new columns is fine, but the "updated" column example is what I'm finally needing.

Comment: Whats the maximum number of ids you have in a row?

Comment: I haven't seen more than 10. Mostly 1-5.

Comment: Why bother with an RDBMS if you're not going to bother with relational data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in SQL, but it's pretty painful because it's going to cause a table-scan of Colors in a correlated subquery.

```
UPDATE Items
SET color_ids = (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Colors.color_name) FROM Colors 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(Colors.id, Items.color_ids));
```

Depending on the size of your tables, this could take a loooooong time to run.

I agree with other comments that this is not the right way to structure data in an relational database, but I sympathize that you're stuck with the design for now, and I assume it would be even more of an interruption to your application to redesign it at this time.

I hope this experience helps you become a developer who does not curse your successor with similar designs!

Comment: Thank you! Just a note to the rare person who might need this: if it needs it don't forget to change your target column to a type that accepts text values.

Answer (score 1):

Never, never, never store multiple values in one column! You should introduce an new table:

```
item_colors
------------
item_id
color_id
```

Example data:

```
item_id |  color_id
      1 |  2
      1 |  5
      2 |  1
      3 |  2
      3 |  3
      3 |  9
```

Your `items` table would then not have a `color_ids` column any more.

Then you can get your desired result like this

```
select i.id, group_concat(c.name) as color_names
from items i
left join item_colors ic on ic.item_id = i.id
join colors c on ic.color_id = c.id
group by i.id
```

Comment: I do appreciate the advice but am looking to update the desired column as presented.

Comment: Well, good luck. It won't be easy. And I am sure you will face other difficulties sticking with that design in the future.